# ՝Vuejs՝ передача `state` в дочерный компонент

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuex

У меня возникла проблема при передаче ՝state՝ из родительского компонента к дочерному.

Вот простой пример из моего кода.

Использую `vuex 4`

Кто может сказать варианты правильной передачи `state`?
Дело в том что в дочерном компоненте не видно уже измененный ՝state՝.
Как я понял рендеринг дочерного компонента произходит ранше чем `projects.commit('setTimezone', this.data)`.

И вообще то что я делаю это правильный подход или нет.

Вот сам код.

```
<template>
    <project-modal ref="ProjectModal"></project-modal>
</template>
import ProjectModal from '@/Pages/Project/Components/CreateUpdateModal'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
      'projects': {
          namespaced: false,
          state: {
              timezones: []
          },
          mutations: {
              setTimezone: (state, timezones) => {
                  state.timezones = timezones;
              },
          },
          getters: {
              timezones: (state) => state.timezones,
          }
      }
    },

})
export default {
    props: [
        'data'
    ],
    data() {
        return {
            'data': this.data
        }
    },
    components: {
        BreezeAuthenticatedLayout,
        BreezeButton,
        toggleObject,
        ProjectModal
    },
    // template: `<option v-for="item in projects.state.timezones" value=""></option>`,

    mounted() {
        store.commit('setTimezone', this.data)
    }
}
```

**Дочерный компонент**

```
<template>
    <select class="custom-select" name="timezone" id="timezone" required>
        Здесь я должен залить  `timezones`
    </select>
</template>


<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        
    },

    mounted() {
        //Выдает пустой массив
        console.log(store.timezones)
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: а если в мутации сделать `state.timezones.push(timezones)`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
<select class="custom-select" name="timezone" id="timezone" required>
           {{ $store.getters('timezones') }}
        </select>
```